# Mysql PDO Invalid credentials causing Internal Server Error rather than catch error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, internal-server-error

I'm more confused than anything, I attempted to connect to my mysql database using PDO. I had invalid credentials and instead of my try and catch catching the error and telling me 'invalid credentials' it completely froze the page and I received this error:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator to inform of the time the error occurred and of anything you might have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

My code is as follows:

```
function pdo_connect(){
    $host           = 'localhost';
    $user           = 'user';
    $pass           = 'wrongpass';
    $dbSchema       = 'wrongschema';
    try{
        $dbcPDO = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbSchema, $user, $pass); //connect to the PDO instance
        $dbcPDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); //turn on errors
        return $dbcPDO;
    }catch(PDOException $e) {
        trigger_error('Could not connect to the database: ' . $e->getMessage());
        return false;
        exit();
    }
}
```

When I have correct credentials I connect with no problem. I would of assumed invalid credentials would be caught by the PDOException and the message stating it failed to connect.

Comment: Your server might be configured to just throw 500 status on notices :-?

Comment: try setting the error attribute as you create the connection `new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbSchema, $user, $pass, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));`

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with PDO, I think it's that fact I have errors turned off. I knew I had errors turned off the part I don't get is I am attempting to turn them on via php. And it kinda works. When the function name didn't exist it told me but I don't think all errors are working.

Comment: What does your error log have to say?

Comment: @meda PDO constructor always throws exceptions on connection errors. Your code shouldn't make any difference. As the OP explains in a followup comment, the problem can possibly be reproduced with a simple `trigger_error('Foo!');` line.

Comment: @Travis If you aren't doing anything special on error (such as showing a friendly error page) my advice is that you just let the exception throw uncaught. You can get for a free a proper log entry with a helpful stack trace. Your current approach is confusing: you downgrade exception to notice and then abort the script suddenly as if it was a fatal error—and you effectively render any error handler useless.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, PDO will catch the exception when we use invalid credentials to the database. Not sure what gave you the issue.

1. You wrote your PDO connecting to the Database in a function. Make sure you call the function inside PHP script.
2. You can use the below code to check, whether the PDO Connection to the database was success.

   ```
   if($con==null)
   {
    $response["connected"] = "false";
   }else{
    $response["connected"] = "true";
   }
   echo json_encode($response);     // $con is the connection object returned.
   ```
3. The code that you used above works fine in my server. Issue may be with the server itself. Try checking the error log more details.

[Link](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204644990/why-am-i-getting-a-500-internal-server-error-message) will guide you to get an idea regarding the Internal server error. Possibly you can post your error log to get the issue fixed quickly.

Best Luck..!!